# "Transfer" a binding from a property to an other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to wrap a `TextBox` in a custom `UserControl` and by then my custom `UserControl` has a `Text` dependency property. An example use of the custom `UserControl` would look like this :

```
<MyTextBoxWrapper Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

and `MyTextBoxWrapper` looks like this :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <TextBox x:Name="wrappedTextBox"/>
</UserControl>
```

I'd like my wrapper to work exactly like if it was written like this :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <TextBox x:Name="wrappedTextBox" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
</UserControl>
```

My issue is that I can't manage to "transfer" the binding from the `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text` property to the `TextBox.Text` property. (kind of like binding the bindings themselves)

I only managed to obtain the binding used by `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text` with this :

```
myTextBoxWrapperInstance.GetBindingExpression(MyTextBoxWrapper.TextProperty);
```

How can I have the same binding being used for both properties? I don't necessarily need the same binding instance but I at least need the binding used by `TextBox.Text` to be created from the binding used by `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `TextBox` in the `UserControl` to the `Text` property of the `UserControl` itself:

```
<TextBox x:Name="wrappedTextBox"
    Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

> This doesn't fit my needs, I need to have the binding on TextBox.Text to be the same binding as the one on MyTextBoxWrapper.Text, what you gave me creates a different binding

Yes, a single binding always has a single target and single source.

You may try to register a callback for the custom `Text` property of the `UserControl` and programmatically bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the same property.

Or make `Text` a property of type `Binding`.

Comment: This doesn't fit my needs, I need to have the binding on `TextBox.Text` to be the same binding as the one on `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text`, what you gave me creates a different binding

Comment: Of course it creates a new binding. A single binding has a single target and single source and it makes no sense to "share" it.

Comment: Well I need to have the `TextBox.Text` bound directly to the property that was given to `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text`'s binding

Comment: @nalka: That's not possible in XAML. What's the custom `Text` property for then?

Comment: I never mentionned I needed the solution to be XAML only, I even mentionned I had found a way to get the binding instance used for `MyTextBoxWrapper.Text` in C#

Comment: `wrappedTextBox` binds to `UserControl.Text` which in turn binds to `SomeProperty`. That's how it works. What's the problem with this setup?

Comment: @nalka: Ok. So register a callback for the `Text` property of the `UserControl` and programmatically bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the same property?

Comment: @nalka: Or make `Text` a property of type `Binding`.

Comment: Making `Text` a property of type `Binding` looks interesting, i'll look into it